# Binder method in java

Tags: java, android

Can anyone explain me this binder class and method

```
 public class LocalBinder extends Binder 
{
    CC2540Service getService() 
    {
        return CC2540Service.this;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) 
{
    return binder;
}

private final IBinder binder = new LocalBinder();
```

I don't really understand this code

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to send and receive data from a service, you need to use a `Binder` object.
The service called CC2540Service simply creates this object and returns a token to it whenever an `Activity` tries to bind to this service.

The only way two processes can transfer data between one and the other is by using these `Binder` tokens. In your case the token is returned via `return binder;`

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing LocalBinder is an inner class of CC2540Service. So CC2540Service.this refers to the instance of CC2540Service.
So it's equivalent to this code

```
class A {
  A a = this;
  class B {
    A getA() {
      return a;
    }
  }
  B getB() {
    return new B();
  }
}
```